# MAPBENDER installtion fail

Tags: php, apache-spark

I have been trying to install Mapbender for several days but in the end I have either this message or the other

```
http://localhost/mapbender/app_dev.php/manager/applications

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

OR

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$loader = require_once(__DIR__ . '/../app/autoload.php');
    
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
    
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Please share your Apache server configuration.

Comment: Also, please share more details about your attempts to resolve the problem. How is this even related to [tag:apache-spark]?